# .NET - Razor outside MVC application - Problems with removing @inherits and providing @model

Tags: .net, razor, buildprovider

**Sorry for the long question. I broke it up into three problems which can be read separately. If you're able to help me with one problem, please do!**

I have a custom implementation of a Razor engine in place. All works and templates are compiled and can be used. There is some implementation at hand which involves a baseclass having a generic `Model` property that allows for strongly typed views (templates). At this point I'm using an `@inherits` directive to define the baseclass and it's generic type.

The answer made by GVS here ([Hosting the Razor View engine using a view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448740/hosting-the-razor-view-engine-using-a-view-model)), where he says that using `@model` is actually shorthand for `@inherits Class<ModelType>` makes me think the two can be interchanged, however this is not the case.

**This is my template**

```
@inherits RazorEngine.TemplateBase<MyProject.TestModel>
@functions {

}
<h1>@Model.TestProperty
```

**Wishlist**

1. Remove the `@inherits` directive
2. Add a `@model` directive

## Problems

---

**Current situation:** Everything compiles and templates can be used. However I have an intellisense error at the `@inherits` directive.:

> There is no buildprovider registered for the extension ".cshtml". You can register one in the  in the machine.config or web.config.

**What's wrong here?**

I have a web.config in the views folder like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>

    <system.web>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

---

**With wishlist #1:**
Removing the `@inherits` directive makes the `.Model` property of the baseclass invisible to visual studio and therefore results in an error => **answer/solution is to implement wishlist #2?**

---

**With wishlist #2:**
Adding the `@model` directive throws the intellisense error on `@Model.TestProperty` (even when leaving the `@inherits` directive in place...):

> The name Model does not exist in the current context.

## Extra info:

I'm using the following code to instantiate a template from the compiled assembly.

```
var template = (RazorTemplateBase<TModel>)Container.CompiledTemplates.CreateInstance("MyNamespace." + entry.TemplateName + "Template");
template.Model = model;
template.DataSource = dataSource;
template.Execute();
var output = template.Buffer.ToString();
template.Buffer.Clear();
return output;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can add a reference to `System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll` (in `<assemblies>`).
   [It registers the `RazorBuildProvider`](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/02/dissecting-razor-part-2-gluing-pieces.html) in a `[PreApplicationStartMethod]`.
2. [the `@model` directive is unique to MVC](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/02/dissecting-razor-part-3-razor-and-mvc.html).
   You need to use the `MvcRazorEngineHost`.

Comment: 1. Adding the reference has no effect. Still no build provider registered... 2. Do i _need_ to? Please see my extra info, i'm using that code to create the template instances.

Comment: @Ropstah: 1. Try explicitly registering the `RazorBuildProvider` in Web.config.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0e51sw9.aspx

Comment: 2. Yes; `@model` is not a standard Razor syntac.  I believe that RazorEngine has its own implementation of it somewhere, but I don't know offhand.

Comment: @SLaks: 1. works, it has to be defined in the main `web.config` though! Which i don't like because this makes my module require configuration changes instead of just a separate web.config which can be automatically inserted.... :( It works though...

Comment: @Ropstah: You should be able to do it yourself in a `[PreApplicationStartMethod]`.

Comment: @SLaks that link is broken, know another?